# What can be used to store generic pci and pci-express cards when they're not installed in a server?

Tags: pci-express

We have a lot of PCI and PCI-express cards, and at any one time a lot of these aren't installed in a server or workstation.  They are in storage.  I'm interested in tips on how to store them.

We keep packaging for a couple of months, so sometimes cards get put back in their original packaging.  But we don't have the space to keep packaging indefinitely.

We have constructed some storage for these cards by taking a hacksaw to old motherboards, and glueing the slot arrays on to wood.  This gets great density, but it's a bit labor intensive to make them.  Plus we have to source the defunct motherboards, get exposed to dust from the sawing, etc.

There must be products that are sold to store currently-unused generic PCI and PCI-Express cards.  But try googling for "PCI-express card storage"!

Has anyone else come up with any solutions for storing these cards, or is anyone able to point at a product that is designed for doing this?

Comment: What's wrong with bulk AS baggies?

Answer (score 7):

Anti-static bags and cardboard boxes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think many people will identify with this.

How many cards are you talking about for density of PCI(e) device storage to matter? Can you be more specific about your constraints? 
Why do you need to retain the cards for so long? It seems like a provisioning issue if you have more inventory on hand than is really necessary.

In my environments, we keep the original packaging. Typically, that packaging is reusable, so there's plenty boxes available. Anti-static bags are a must, especially if cardboard boxes are lined with protective foam, etc.

The best option if you need extreme density or are working with a lot of cards and need them to be accessible is a PCB or circuit board rack. [**Fancort** makes several universal varieties...](http://www.fancort.com/Products/Racks-and-Fixtures/Universal-Racks.html)

[image]

[image]

[**As well as adjustable racks:**](http://www.fancort.com/Products/Racks-and-Fixtures/Adjustable-Racks/Karry-All-Model-76.html)

[image]

Comment: Don't these racks/devices need to be within a Static safe environment to be effective ?

Comment: I linked to the ESD models. But more context is needed. Anything is better than hacksawed PCIe sockets glued onto wood.

Comment: Unless they're in an SHA then it doesn't really matter - theyre all as bad as each other.